# JaCoCo (Offline Instrumentation) in <goal>instrument</goal> analyzes the entire pom.xml. But I need only the tests part

Tags: java, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Basically I need jacoco only instrument the tests part, but is instrumententing the entire pom.xml, and the report came with everything (Data from “oracle.jdbc.driver”, “com.mysql.jdbc”… etc.)

I've been trying for a couple of days with almost everything. But I have not succeeded so far

Notice here how **jacoco:instrument** instrument the entire pom.xml

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:instrument (default-instrument) @ myApp ---
...
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.firstPackage.tdz:myApp:X.1.0 @ C:\rootFolder\my_app\server\MyApp\pom.xml
```

And my tests run in

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myApp ---
[DEBUG] Source directories: [C:\rootFolder\my_app\server\myApp\tests\src]
[DEBUG] Classpath: [C:\devel\my_app\server\myApp\target\test-classes
```

This is my maven flow:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ myApp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3582 source files to c:\rootFolder\my_app\server\myApp\target\classes
...
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.3:compile (default) @ myApp ---
...
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:instrument (default-instrument) @ myApp ---
...
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myApp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 326 source files to c:\rootFolder\my_app\server\myApp\target\test-classes
...
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.3:test-compile (default) @ myApp ---
...
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.15:test (default-test) @ myApp ---

... finally

[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:restore-instrumented-classes (default-restore-instrumented-classes) @ myApp ---
...
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:report (default-report) @ myApp ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file c:\devel\my_app\server\MyApp\target\jacoco.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'myApp' with 5562 classes
```

Any real example here would be great In "Jacoco default-instrument" for run only tests part. It is that possible?

```
<execution>
      <id>default-instrument</id>
      <goals>
         <goal>instrument</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
      <!-- any real example here? Notice maven's behavior above -->
      </configuration>
  </execution>
```

Comment: can you post the whole JaCoCo plugin section... not just the execution section.

Comment: stackoverflow don't allow me to edit my questions since I am a new Contributor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [`jacoco:instrument`](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/instrument-mojo.html) and [`jacoco:report`](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html) operate with `target/classes`, because this is the classes that are executed and whose coverage is measured.

If you place in `target/classes` more classes than in `src`, then without corresponding `inclusions` / `exclusions` they will also be instrumented and reported.

Please note that exclusion of classes from `instrumentation` is not enough to exclude classes from `report` - quoting [JaCoCo FAQ](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/faq.html):

> report generator cannot distinguish whether the class was excluded from instrumentation or not executed

So please make sure that you properly configured execution of **both `instrument` and `report` goals**. Maven allows many different ways to configure different executions of different goals, here is just one of examples:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <execution>
    <goals>
      <goal>instrument</goal>
      <goal>report</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <!-- this configuration affects this "execution" of "instrument" and "report" goals -->
      <excludes>*</excludes>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
```

Comment: That didn't worked for me w/ Jacoco version 0.8.5. But declaring excludes on top level of plugin (plugin/configuration/excludes/exclude ... ) worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<includes>` tag and put in there your package default.

```
<execution>
      <id>default-instrument</id>
      <goals>
         <goal>instrument</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
           <includes> my/package/** </includes>
      </configuration>
</execution>
```

[reference](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/instrument-mojo.html#includes)